# Image Processing in C

Tags: c++, windows, image-processing

Can someone suggest some good image processing library in C/c++ that can work easily in Visual studio .I need to do some 3-D modeling and Image reconstruction (would involve lot of pixel value access).I am looking for something that has a good documentation/online support apart from given functionality.

I am currently trying CImg but want your opinion before I proceed with project.

Comment: Your title says C, your question says C/C++ and mentions Visual Studio, and your tags say C++. Which language are you trying to write in? I'm guessing C++?

Answer (score 2):

The tags *c++ image graphics processing* naturally lead me to post a link to [openCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)

Comment: Why was I downvoted? OP asked for a suggestion, and i made one.

Comment: Why -1? I was about to install OpenCV for the project isnt it good?

Comment: @Manish: From what I know, OpenCV is very good. I worked on at least two commercial projects which used OpenCV, though I never got into touch with the library myself (as i was working on the lower layers of the Projects)

Comment: I've used OpenCV personally before. Don't think it can be used for 3D modelling... it's more for doing this like image recognition, and running filters on images. Scientific things (image -> data), not artsy things (data -> images). I believe it should allow pixel-level access, but if that's all you want, something like libSDL might be more appropriate.

Comment: 3D modeling and image reconstructions are scientific, not artsy. I'd have some hesistations about OpenCV too, but only because of the 3D parts. OpenCV is templated on pixel type, but not dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

[Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) by Intel.

Answer (score 1):

- [ITK (InsightToolkit)](http://www.itk.org) - for multi-dimensional datasets
- [VTK (VisualizationToolkit)](http://www.vtk.org) - for visualization, but also a little bit for ImageProcessing
- OpenCV - normally for 2D, but very fast.
- Matlab - should only be used for 2D (MATrix LABoratory) and not for big datasets
- Mathematica - ... also I would say: 2D
- Boost - can sometimes be helpfully for the analysis
- CGAL - can also be used for feature extraction

Answer (score 0):

i tried Cairo (http://cairographics.org/samples/) for a project in past.

g2 library (http://g2.sourceforge.net/) also has quite comprehensive features. bit old though.

Answer (score 0):

Another such library is [ITK](http://www.itk.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Most useful image processing libraries in C/C++ are OpenCV and ITK.They are most commonly used libraries for image processing. Because they have good documentations, world-wide support with mail lists or forums.Also, they are both open source libraries which written with c++. ITK is actually used for medical image processing.But you can use for every type of image.And opencv has very large functions on image processing,computer vision and machine learning.In high level application you couldn't seperate one of them from each other.Image proc.,comp. vis. and machine learning intertwine with each other.Also both openCV and ITK can be used with any other c++ based library such as qt for gui,vtk for visualisation etc. Also you can use opencv and itk together.OpenCV and itk such a big advantage to process images for who familiar C/C++ also python.